# string pattaren-matching using awk

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, gawk

(Couldn't come with any better title)

I'm trying to convert a number of lines, like these:

```
#define GENERIC_TYPE_METER_PULSE                     0x30 /*Pulse Meter*/
#define SPECIFIC_TYPE_NOT_USED                       0x00 /*Specific Device Class not used*/
......
#define MFG_ID_WAYNE_DALTON                          0x0008   //Wayne Dalton
#define MFG_ID_WILSHINE_HOLDING_CO_LTD               0x012D   //Wilshine Holding Co., Ltd
#define MFG_ID_WIDOM                                 0x0149   //wiDom
......
#define COMMAND_CLASS_ALARM                              0x71
#define COMMAND_CLASS_ALARM_V2                           0x71
#define COMMAND_CLASS_NOTIFICATION_V3                    0x71
#define COMMAND_CLASS_NOTIFICATION_V4                    0x71
```

in a file (c++) to something like these (for Java):

```
SPECIFIC_TYPE_NOT_USED((byte)0x00)             /*Specific Device Class not used*/
MFG_ID_WILSHINE_HOLDING_CO_LTD((byte)0x012D)   //Wilshine Holding Co., Ltd
COMMAND_CLASS_ALARM((byte)0x71)
....
```

I came up with this:

```
gawk '/^#define/ && / [[:xdigit:]]/ { printf "%s((byte)%s)\n",$2,$3 }'
```

but there are two issues - it doesn't work with `awk`; requires GNU-awk (`gawk`) and I also need the end-of-the-line comments in the output whenever available. How can I do that? I'm especially interested using `awk` but can live with `sed` as well. Cheers!!

Comment: Which part needs gawk? You can match hex digits with an ordinary character class `0x[0-9a-fA-F]+`

Comment: @Barmar: some reason `0x[0-9a-fA-F]+` did not work for me. Hopefully I wasn't missing anything. Hence tried `gawk` and got better result. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one `sed` solution, i just tested once, so first test some cases

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ cat log; echo "########";sed -e 's/#define \([^ ]*\)[ ]*\([^ ]*\)/\1((byte)\2)/g' log
#define GENERIC_TYPE_METER_PULSE                     0x30 /*Pulse Meter*/
#define SPECIFIC_TYPE_NOT_USED                       0x00 /*Specific Device Class not used*/
#define MFG_ID_WAYNE_DALTON                          0x0008   //Wayne Dalton
#define MFG_ID_WILSHINE_HOLDING_CO_LTD               0x012D   //Wilshine Holding Co., Ltd
#define MFG_ID_WIDOM                                 0x0149   //wiDom
#define COMMAND_CLASS_ALARM                              0x71
#define COMMAND_CLASS_ALARM_V2                           0x71
#define COMMAND_CLASS_NOTIFICATION_V3                    0x71
#define COMMAND_CLASS_NOTIFICATION_V4                    0x71
########
GENERIC_TYPE_METER_PULSE((byte)0x30) /*Pulse Meter*/
SPECIFIC_TYPE_NOT_USED((byte)0x00) /*Specific Device Class not used*/
MFG_ID_WAYNE_DALTON((byte)0x0008)   //Wayne Dalton
MFG_ID_WILSHINE_HOLDING_CO_LTD((byte)0x012D)   //Wilshine Holding Co., Ltd
MFG_ID_WIDOM((byte)0x0149)   //wiDom
COMMAND_CLASS_ALARM((byte)0x71)
COMMAND_CLASS_ALARM_V2((byte)0x71)
COMMAND_CLASS_NOTIFICATION_V3((byte)0x71)
COMMAND_CLASS_NOTIFICATION_V4((byte)0x71)
[[bash_prompt$]]$
```

for a proper format, ( in my sense, it is aligning the comment ) , i was not able to come up with any `sed` solution, ( i am interested in one ) here is an `awk` solution ( looks like a little clumsy, but self explanatory..

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ awk '{str=sprintf("%s((byte)%s)", $2, $3);len=length(str); \
> for(i=50;i>len;i--) str=sprintf("%s ", str); print str (NF>3?substr($0,index($0,$4)):"")}' log
GENERIC_TYPE_METER_PULSE((byte)0x30)              /*Pulse Meter*/
SPECIFIC_TYPE_NOT_USED((byte)0x00)                /*Specific Device Class not used*/
MFG_ID_WAYNE_DALTON((byte)0x0008)                 //Wayne Dalton
MFG_ID_WILSHINE_HOLDING_CO_LTD((byte)0x012D)      //Wilshine Holding Co., Ltd
MFG_ID_WIDOM((byte)0x0149)                        //wiDom
COMMAND_CLASS_ALARM((byte)0x71)
COMMAND_CLASS_ALARM_V2((byte)0x71)
COMMAND_CLASS_NOTIFICATION_V3((byte)0x71)
COMMAND_CLASS_NOTIFICATION_V4((byte)0x71)
```

Comment: thanks! can we also left-align the comment (2nd in the output) column? Cheers!!

Comment: see the edited answer, actually, my idea is there must be another way to pad the string with spaces, but at this moment, nothing comes to my mind, so you can keep looking for a better way,

Comment: That's was exactly the reason I started with awk in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this awk one-liner:

```
awk '$1=="#define" && $3~/[0-9]+$/{printf "%s((byte)%s)", $2, $3; $1=$2=$3=""; print}' file
```

**EDIT:** Here is an awk that you can try for better alignment of comments:

```
awk '$1 == "#define" && $3 ~ /[0-9]+$/{s=sprintf("%s((byte)%s)", $2, $3); $1=$2=$3="";
     printf("%-50s\t%s\n", s, $0)}'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
GENERIC_TYPE_METER_PULSE((byte)0x30)                      /*Pulse Meter*/
SPECIFIC_TYPE_NOT_USED((byte)0x00)                        /*Specific Device Class not used*/
MFG_ID_WAYNE_DALTON((byte)0x0008)                         //Wayne Dalton
MFG_ID_WIDOM((byte)0x0149)                                //wiDom
COMMAND_CLASS_ALARM((byte)0x71)                           
COMMAND_CLASS_ALARM_V2((byte)0x71)                        
COMMAND_CLASS_NOTIFICATION_V3((byte)0x71)                 
COMMAND_CLASS_NOTIFICATION_V4((byte)0x71)
```

Comment: I'm also trying to align the comment column; it's all getting messed up when I try to do that.

Comment: Hmm that wasn't part of your question :)

Comment: yes, I know; just being greedy!! Also what does `$1=$2=$3=""` do/mean?

Comment: OK I am on mobile now. Will work it in an hour to get alignment of comments.

Comment: Here is an awk that you can try for better alignment of comments: **`awk '$1 == "#define" && $3 ~ /[0-9]+$/{s=sprintf("%s((byte)%s)", $2, $3); $1=$2=$3=""; printf("%-50s\t%s\n", s, $0)}'`**

Comment: Answering your previous question: `$1=$2=$3=""` makes first 3 fields empty in the each record after we have already populated our output string `s`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^#/ {
    hd[++nr] = sprintf("%s((byte)%s)", $2, $3)
    lgth = length(hd[nr])
    maxLgth = (lgth > maxLgth ? lgth : maxLgth)

    sub(/[^/]+/,"")
    tl[nr] = $0
}

END {
    for (i=1; i<=nr; i++)
        printf "%-*s%s\n", maxLgth+2, hd[i], tl[i]
}
$ awk -f tst.awk file
GENERIC_TYPE_METER_PULSE((byte)0x30)          /*Pulse Meter*/
SPECIFIC_TYPE_NOT_USED((byte)0x00)            /*Specific Device Class not used*/
MFG_ID_WAYNE_DALTON((byte)0x0008)             //Wayne Dalton
MFG_ID_WILSHINE_HOLDING_CO_LTD((byte)0x012D)  //Wilshine Holding Co., Ltd
MFG_ID_WIDOM((byte)0x0149)                    //wiDom
COMMAND_CLASS_ALARM((byte)0x71)
COMMAND_CLASS_ALARM_V2((byte)0x71)
COMMAND_CLASS_NOTIFICATION_V3((byte)0x71)
COMMAND_CLASS_NOTIFICATION_V4((byte)0x71)
```

Change the `2` in `maxLgth+2` to whatever spacing you want between the longest value and it's associated comment.