# sed right align a group of text

Tags: bash, sed

this question originated from [string pattaren-matching using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587314/string-pattaren-matching-using-awk) , basically we are splitting a line of text in multiple groups based on a regex pattern, and then printing two groups only. Now the question is can we right align a group while printing through `sed`?
below is an example

```
$cat input.txt
it is line one
it is longggggggg one
itttttttttt is another one
```

now

```
$sed -e 's/\(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\)/\1 \3/g' input.txt
```

it splits and prints group 1 and 3, but the output is

```
it line
it longggggggg
itttttttttt another
```

my question is can we do it through `sed` so that the output comes as

```
it                             line
it                      longggggggg
itttttttttt                 another
```

I did it with `awk` but I feel it can be done through `sed`, but I am not able to get how I am going to get the length of the second group and then pad correct number of spaces in between the groups, I am open to any suggestions to try out.

Comment: I don't think it can be done with `sed`, it doesn't have arithmetic or formatting operations.

Comment: This is what `awk` does without any problem. So I would not have used time to solve this, unless your computer does not have `awk`

Comment: @Jotne He said he already did it with awk.

Comment: Given that `awk` can do it almost trivially and anything that achieves the result in `sed` will be inscrutable and contorted beyond imagining, I won't spend any time thinking about how to use what is clearly the wrong tool for this job (`sed`); use `awk` (or Perl, or Python, or ...) to do the job.

Comment: @Barmar This I alrady know. But I just pointed out this is a job for the right tool, and in this case its `awk`. If you look at the `sed`solution provided here, none of them are easy to understand.  For any new to `sed` they would not have understand much.  This simple `awk` does the job: `awk '{printf "%-15s %20s\n",$1,$3}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(.*) .* (.*) .*$/\1 \2/;:a;s/^.{1,40}$/ &/;ta;s/^( *)(\S*)/\2\1/' file
```

or:

```
sed -r 's/^(.*) .* (.*) .*$/printf "%-20s%20s" \1 \2/e' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use looping in sed to achieve what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'aa bb cc dd
11 22 33333333 44
ONE TWO THREEEEEEEEE FOUR' | \
sed -e 's/\(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\)/\1 \3/g' \
-e '/\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)/ { :x ; s/^\(.\{1,19\}\) \(.\{1,19\}\)$/\1  \2/g ; tx }'
```

The two 19's control the width of your columns. The `:x` is a label which is looped to by `tx` whenever the preceding substitution succeeded. (You could add a `p;` before tx to "debug" it.

Answer (score 0):

It most easy to use `awk` in this case...

You could too use a bash loop to calculate the number of space and run this command on the line covered :

```
while read; do
    # ... calculate $SPACE ...
    echo $REPLY|sed "s/\([^\ ]*\)\ *[^\ ]*\ *\([^\ ]*\)/\1$SPACES\2/g"
done < file
```

But I prefer use `awk` for do all that (or other advanced shell languages ​​such as Perl, Python, PHP shell mode, ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
TemplateSpace="                                                      "
TemplateSize=${#TemplateSpace}

sed "
# split your group (based on word here but depend on your real need)
s/^ *\(\w\) \(\w\) \(\w\) \(\w\).*$/\1 \3/

# align
s/$/${TemplateSpace}/
s/^\(.\{${TemplateSize}\}\).*$/\1/
s/\(\w\) \(\w\)\( *\)/\1 \3\2/
"
```

or more simple for avoiding TemplateSize (and there are no dot in content)

```
TemplateSpace="............................................................."
```

and replace

```
s/^\(.\{${TemplateSize}\}.*$/\1/
```

by

```
s/^\(${TemplateSpace}\).*$/\1/
s/\./ /g
```

Answer (score 0):

Del columns 2 and 4. Right justify resulting col 2 at line length of 23 chars.

```
sed -e '
 s/[^ ]\+/                       /4;
 s/[^ ]\+//2;
 s/^\(.\{23\}\).*$/\1/;
 s/\(^[^ ]\+[ ]\+\)\([^ ]\+\)\([ ]\+\)/\1\3\2/;
'
```

or gnu sed with extended regex:

```
sed -r '
 s/\W+\w+\W+(\w+)\W+\w+$/\1                       /;
 s/^(.{23}).*/\1/;
 s/(+\W)(\w+)(\W+)$/\1\3\2/
'
```

Answer (score -1):

This question is old, but I like to see it as a puzzle.
While I love the loop solution for its brevity, here is one without a loop or shell help.

```
sed -E "s/ \w+ (\w+) \w+$/ \1/;h;s/./ /g;s/$/#                       /;s/( *)#\1//;x;H;x;s/\n//;s/^( *)(\w+)/\2\1/"
```

or without extended regex

```
sed "s/ .* \(.*\) .*$/ \1/;h;s/./ /g;s/$/#                       /;s/\( *\)#\1//;x;H;x;s/\n//;s/^\( *\)\([^ ]*\)/\2\1/"
```